# How to efficiently use numpy random choice for varying weight list

Tags: python, numpy, random

I am trying to use the function `np.random.choice` to randomly choose numbers from a list whose weights are in a list of lists. That is, for every row I want to generate one number. It is possible to do it with `for` loop as follows,

```
from numpy.random import choice

W_list = np.array([[0.9,0.1],
                   [0.95,0.05],
                   [0.85,0.15]])
number_list = []
for i in range(len(W_list)):
    number_list.extend(choice([0, 1], size=1, p=W_list[i]).tolist())

number_list

[0,0,0]
```

The `p` parameter needs to 1D, hence it is not possible to use `p=W_list`. Is there any way to do this more efficiently without using the `for` loop?

Comment: number_list=[choice(i) for i in W_list]

Comment: @Sterling. That's no more vectorized than the `for` loop

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question then. I don't know what you mean when you say vectorized. Can you explain?

Comment: @Sterling. I posted an answer that demonstrates. Vectorizing means offloading all loops to the C implementation in numpy. Ironically, np.vectorize does not do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the simple case of a single boolean per row, you can do this very easily by implementing the way probabilities are applied by hand:

```
cumulative_weights = W_list.cumsum(axis=1)
number_arr = (np.random.rand(3, 1) < cumulative_weights).argmax(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I want to generate just 3 binary values from this random choice. With the first method, I am getting a (3,2) shape array with 1s mostly, where with given probability, I should be getting mostly 0s.
And for the last method, I am getting this error,
"non-broadcastable output operand with shape (3,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (3,2)"

Comment: @TanzinFarhat. Sorry about that. Fixed now. I had forgotten to call argmax on the result.